# Unable to display usernames on Assets index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create an index page where all assets are displayed including a link to the user who they are assigned to, however when I use

```
def index
 @assets = Asset.paginate(page: params[:page])
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

It returns - couldn't find User without an ID.

index.html.erb - Assets

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Assets') %>
<h1>All assets</h1>
<%= will_paginate @assets %>
<ol class="assets">
    <%= render @assets %>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate @assets %>
```

_asset.html.erb partial

```
<li>
<span class="id">JTC<%= asset.id %></span>
<span class="serial"><%= asset.serial_no %></span>
<span class="status">Status: <%= asset.status %></span>
<span class="type">Type: <%= asset.asset_type %><br/></span>
<span class="description">Description: <%= asset.asset_description %><br /></span>
<span class="comment"><em><%= asset.comment %></em></span>
<span class="timestamp">
    <br />Added <%= time_ago_in_words(asset.created_at) %> ago. <br /> Assigned to: <%= link_to 
    @user.name %>
    <br />Date Purchased: <%= asset.date_purchased %> 
</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@user = User.find(params[:id])` is expecting a URL along the lines of `/assets/40`, where 40 is the id (and even then that wouldn't make sense, since the 40 should be the id of the asset, not the user). When you just access `/assets`, there is no id parameter, so it tries to basically do `User.find(nil)`, which gives you that error.

Assuming assets belong to users, you should just get rid of the `@user = User.find(params[:id])` line in your controller, and change your partial to use `asset.user.name` instead of `@user.name`.

To avoid an N+1 query situation on your users, you could update your controller to use this:

```
@assets = Asset.includes(:user).paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Comment: That's displaying the user name now, thanks. Unfortunately the link_to doesn't seem to work. I'm sure I'll cope though.

Comment: link_to needs two parameters: a title, and a link or resource. Try `<%= link_to asset.user.name, asset.user %>`.

Comment: Thanks, I feel really dumb for not thinking to try that before mentioning link_to not working.